# How to setup different configuration(awsconfiguration.json) with AWSMobileClient for debug and release build types

Tags: android, aws-sdk

I want to have different configuration for `debug` and `release` builds. All the configuration is stored inside `awsconfiguration.json`, for example I have two different config files how can I set which file should be used.

When using `AWSMobileClient.getInstance()` it gets default configuration from file `awsconfiguration.json`

Configuration file example:

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
        "Region": "DIFFERENT_VALUES"
      }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
      "AppClientSecret": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
      "AppClientId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
      "PoolId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
      "Region": "DIFFERENT_VALUES"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**
There is option to use different `awsconfiguration.json` by puting different files in `main\res\raw` and `release\res\raw`, for example by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740076/1307690) and it works. 
But I'm wondering whether there is an option to do it programmatically.

Comment: how to generate awsconfiguration.json in android studio?

Answer (score 11):

This can also be acheived by setting the configuration value in AWSConfiguration and then initializing the AWSMobileClient.

```
    AWSConfiguration awsConfiguration = new AWSConfiguration(context);
    awsConfiguration.setConfiguration("Stage"); // BuildConfig can be used here.

    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(context, awsConfiguration,  new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
        }
    });
```

And the awsconfiguration.json file can be updated as below

```
{
 "Version": "1.0",
 "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
            "Region": "DIFFERENT_VALUES"
        },
        "Stage": {
            "PoolId": "STAGE_VALUES",
            "Region": "STAGE_VALUES"
        }
    }
 },
 "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {},
    "Stage": {}
 },
 "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
        "AppClientSecret": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
        "AppClientId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
        "PoolId": "DIFFERENT_VALUES",
        "Region": "DIFFERENT_VALUES"
    },
    "Stage": {
        "AppClientSecret": "STAGE_VALUES",
        "AppClientId": "STAGE_VALUES",
        "PoolId": "STAGE_VALUES",
        "Region": "STAGE_VALUES"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: how to generate awsconfiguration.json in android studio?

Comment: Amplify.Auth continues using Default even after doing this.

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can use separate CognitoUserPools from the AmplifyConfiguration.json file apart from the normal Default() one? I can't get it to change from default to use another such as Prod etc... (iOS App)

Answer (score 8):

I've been trying to achieve something similar; selecting an AWS configuration at runtime based on a selected profile. I got it partially working  by hacking the AWS SDK but then stumbled across [release notes](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/releases/tag/2.11.0) for AWS SDK version [2.11.0](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/releases/tag/2.11.0). Quoting:

> Added the option of passing the configuration as an in-memory object (i.e. `[String: Any]/NSDictionary`) instead of the default `awsconfiguration.json` through the new API

I've also found it documented(!) in the amplify getting started guide [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/manualsetup#configure-using-an-in-memory-object).

So since 9th September 2019 it **IS** possible to select an AWS configuration at runtime.

---

**Edit:** Just noticed that this question is for Android rather than iOS. I'm not an Android developer but a quick searched revealed something similar in AWS Android SDK release [2.13.6](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.13.6) (7th June 2019). Quoting the [release notes](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.13.6):

> Add `AWSConfiguration(JSONObject)` constructor to construct a `AWSConfiguration` object from the configuration passed via a JSONObject

... which looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_source_sets); eg. directories `main` & `debug` or directories `debug` & `release`, where `res/raw` or `assets` are not being processed by AAPT2. Adding credentials alike that is only suggested for internal use, because they can be easily extracted from the package.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I want to change it dynamically, for example, programmatically if there is such option.

Comment: Gradle configurations are fully script-able, so what's the problem? Adding credentials into the source code is a certain attack vector and therefore absolutely not suggested, no matter how often people may up-vote these "simple but Swiss cheese" answers.

Answer (score -1):

Abhishek's answer is my favorite of these.  But if you're using Amplify (as I am), while it's possible to put multiple configurations into a single file, I've not found a way of selecting between them.

So, although it's not an exact answer to the question, in Amplify you can select between multiple, self-contained configuration files like this:

When you set up Amplify:

```
Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
// and whatever other plugins you'll need...
Amplify.configure(AmplifyConfiguration.fromConfigFile(applicationContext, getConfigResourceId(applicationContext)), applicationContext)
```

And also add:

```
private fun getConfigResourceId(context: Context): Int = context.resources.getIdentifier("YourConfigFileName", "raw", context.packageName)
```

Comment: how to generate awsconfiguration.json in android studio?

Comment: @bdevloper You don't generate awsConfigurations in Android Studio.  You generate them in Amplify, and then save them in the res directory, where Android Studio can find them.